redis connection not working with go-redis?
I cannot connect to my local redis through my go project.
I am starting redis using docker compose like so:
  redis:
    image: redis:6.2.3-alpine
    platform: linux/x86_64
    ports:
      - 6379:6379

I'm trying to connect to this in my go project like this:
func connect()*RedisConnection {
    opts := &redis.Options{
        Addr:     "localhost:6379",
        Password: "",
        DB:       0,
    }
    opts.TLSConfig = &tls.Config{
        InsecureSkipVerify: true,
    }

    client := redis.NewClient(opts)
    opts.OnConnect = func(ctx context.Context, cn *redis.Conn) error {
        log.Info().Msgf("connected to redis..")
        return nil
    }
    if err := client.Ping(ctx).Err(); err != nil {
        log.Info().Msgf(err.Error())
    }

    return &RedisConnection{
        redisClient: client,
    }

However this constantly fails and I get a "context deadline exceeded error".
I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong?

Too little information: We don't know your context, no do you tell us where you get this error. Please post a reproducible example.

Are you running your application inside docker as well? Is the redis container running? Note: Just because you started it it is by no means sure that it is running.

Could be a problem of network binding. You are trying to connect to localhost:6379 but maybe docker is binding the redis port in another interface. Please modify Addr:     "localhost:6379", to Addr:     ":6379", or to Addr:     "0.0.0.0:6379",.
Note that this should be avoided on a production system and you should always specify the IP address.
